# JQuery Validation - adding spacing only if an error exists?

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm creating a form with several discrete sections. Validation is Jquery validate and I'm going to show the errors  appear together at the top of each section. I've found that if an error displays, I need to have a bit of extra spacing between the error block and the start of the form fields.  The error placement adds the error to a div with the id of 'infoError'. The code for the error placement is as follows:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.hasClass("firstName")) {
        error.appendTo("#infoError");
    } else if (element.hasClass("lastName")) {
        error.appendTo("#infoError");
    } else if (element.hasClass("address")) {
        error.appendTo("#infoError");
    }
}
```

I need to know how to add a class to the infoError div or an extra div or something to add a little bit of space to the end of the inforError div but only if an error is displayed. Should I do another condition to add another append if any of those error elements are active or is there a different, more elegant way to accomplish the same thing?

Thanks in advance.

### EDIT

I see that I wasn't as clear as I thought in my question, so I've added a couple of images to illustrate the point. I've pixelated all of the form fields and messages due to PPI concerns where I work.

The first image shows the form section before submission with spacing between the legend and the top of the fields.
[image: Spacing prior to submitting form]
The second image show the same form section with the error block and you can clearly see where the error block is right on top of the form fields. This is where I want to add additional spacing or a class but only in the event that the error block is displayed.  Does that help clarify?
[image: Spacing after submitting form with errors. Need more spacing between errors and fields but only if errors are present.]

Comment: Instead of  `error.appendTo("#infoError");` you can use string concatenation like `$("infoError").html("<p>"+error+"</p>")`. Here `error` is a variable containing the error text which you can get separately.

Comment: Can you please share code?

Answer (score 0):

```
#infoError {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

You can choose a value rather than 10px based on your need.